# Adding variables together in a Java if statement

Tags: java

I have a variable, `HEADER_DIFF`. It is set using:

```
public static final long HEADER_DIFF = 76;
```

I then have this call:

```
  private static byte[] copyToByteArray(final InputStream is,
          final int recordLength, final boolean enforceLength)
      throws IOException {

    BoundedInputStream bis = new BoundedInputStream(is, recordLength);
    byte[] rawContents = IOUtils.toByteArray(bis);
    if (!(rawContents.length == recordLength + HEADER_DIFF
          || rawContents.length == recordLength)) {
      LOG.error("Read " + rawContents.length + " bytes but expected "
      + recordLength + " bytes. Continuing...");
    }
    return rawContents;
  }
```

The problem is, `recordLength` is not being added to `HEADER_DIFF` when we do the if statement. Indeed, if I in the `LOG` decide to print `recordLength + HEADER_DIFF` I simply get `recordLength`.

Any idea of how to make this work?

Comment: I find that very difficult to believe.  Can you construct a [minimal test case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If I swap the error out to `LOG.error("This never appears!" + (recordLength + HEADER_DIFF));` I get the value `recordLength` not `recordLength` + 76. I am probably doing something stupid or is it to do with the `final` nature of variables?

Comment: @programming_historian, try to print out these variables separately, what do you see?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko If I print them using `System.out.println` they do indeed work properly. I'm going to try @JGibbers' solution below.

Comment: @programming_historian are you sure you want to increase the actual value of record_length by HEADER_DIFF? If you do that, then the next test `rawContents.length == recordLength` will compare with the *updated* recordLength!

Comment: Maybe `recordLength` is actually 76 bytes less than you think it is?